# Bookmark look up confusion

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing, sql-execution-plan

New versions of SQL Management Studio render a bookmark lookup as in the picture below. That makes me think the operation is independent from Index Seek (and can run in parallel?). Shouldn't Index Seek finish first? Its output (physical row IDs) is the input for Key Lookup, right?

[image: Execution plan sample]

Comment: But consider what `Nested Loops` does - it executes the second operator for each result produced by the first one - so as soon as *one* result is made available from the index seek, the key lookup for that result can occur in parallel with the seek continuing.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks! Can you post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan in your question shows a key lookup. This type of lookup uses a logical identifier (the clustered index key) not physical as stated in your question.

The operation is not independent from the Index Seek as the index seek returns the logical key value that is being looked up in the key lookup.

The execution plan shown in your screenshot is serial not parallel. It runs on a single thread so it is not the case that another thread will be busy doing the key lookups whilst the first one is performing the index seeks.

It is possible to get a parallel plan with key lookups

[image]

However this partitions the rows into different threads and each thread effectively operates as a serial plan on its own set of rows so it still isn't the case that the iterators for a particular set of rows will be operating independently in parallel.

For either a serial or parallel plan the nested loops operator may use [prefetch](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/08/31/sql-server-internals-nested-loops-prefetching.aspx) however. This issues asynchronous I/Os for pages that will be needed by the inner side of the nested loops join (in this case by the key lookup)

> An unordered prefetch allows the inner side of the join to proceed
>   using data from whichever I/Os happened to complete first.